# Writing code into element attribute using Python and lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I would like to use lxml/xpath to find certain img elements and write a short php script into their src attributes. Like so:

```
from lxml import html

htmldoc = html.document_fromstring(htmlstr)
imgs = htmldoc.xpath("//*[@class='someclass']/img")
imgs[0].attrib['src'] = "<?php echo get_img_file(); ?>"
processedHTML = html.tostring(htmldoc, pretty_print=True)

with open("test.php","w+") as outfile:
    outfile.write(processedHTML.decode("utf-8"))
```

Illegal characters (such as < and >) are escaped as html entities. Is there a way to set lxml to allow these characters to be written to the document? Thanks!